# Place comments inside a multi-line list literal

Tags: python, list, comments, literals

I am doing an optimization problem and writing a gigantic list. I would like to insert comments inside the list like below

```
my_rhs = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,\ #comment1
         -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,\ #comment2
          0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

but when I do this Python gives an error. How can I comment in the places shown? I tried defining each line as a new list and using `+` to append but that doesn't seem to work either. Like below

```
my_rhs = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]+\ #comment1
         [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0]+\ #comment2
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

How can I comment in the shown locations without Python giving an error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You simply need to remove the backslash characters:

```
my_rhs = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, # comment1
         -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  # comment2
          0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> my_rhs = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, # comment1
...          -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  # comment2
...           0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> my_rhs
[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>>
```

The `\` character tells Python that the following line is part of the current line.  So, it interprets this:

```
my_rhs = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,\ #comment1
         -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,\ #comment2
          0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

As being equivalent to this:

```
my_rhs = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, #comment1 -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, #comment2 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

It is noteworthy that [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official style-guide for Python code, has a section on wrapping long lines:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.

This excerpt from [Explicit Line Joining](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) is also relevant:

> A line ending in a backslash cannot carry a comment. A backslash does
>   not continue a comment. A backslash does not continue a token except
>   for string literals (i.e., tokens other than string literals cannot be
>   split across physical lines using a backslash). A backslash is illegal
>   elsewhere on a line outside a string literal.

Comment: this an awesome answer!....Thanks!....I wish I could upvote but i don't seem to have a "reputation" around here.